# Write blob string into a file via Perl

Tags: perl, module, blob

I have a blob srting (a jpg image) in perl. How can I write it into a jpg file to disk on the server using perl?

I found [File::BLOB](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::BLOB) module on CPAN, but it is not clear it can convert file to blob only, or it can convert blob to file too.

The File::BLOB capability to blob to file conversion or is there any other working module or process to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just open a filehandle, set it to [binary mode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) and write out your data.

```
open my $fh, '>', 'foo.jpg' or die $!;
binmode $fh;
print $fh $blob;
close $fh;
```

Also take a look at [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html).